# How can a method from an interface can be called in the given project? (Whether I'm wrong?)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm

[This](https://github.com/Ralffss/polygons) is the project I'm trying to understand. I'm trying to understand what goes after what in this project. What confuses me, is that `getFeatures()` call in `ViewModel`. It seems that it calls an abstract function in the interface which is implemented in the file `DefaultMapsRepository`. I don't understand how it works. I thought that call should be of function from `DefaultMapsRepository` class where `getFeatures()` is implemented. So, as I understand, `getFeatures()` call in `ViewModel` calls the not implemented method from the interface and then that interface somehow finds the implementation of it and that `override fun getFeatures()` code runs its body. Correct me if I'm wrong. But If I create another implementation of `getFeatures()` how would that interface choose which implementation to use? I heard somewhere that `interface` of repository makes code easier to test but it's hard to understand how if I don't know how this all code works. I sometimes like to test how code works in the console to make code look simpler but I can't replicate the same situation because I'm not able to run the code if I add something to `fun main()` constructor. I think such structure of a project is used a lot and I want to understand it very well.

Answer (score 2):

An interface is just a contract. If `CoolInterface` has a property `someValue: Int` and a method `doThing(): Boolean`, then anything that implements that interface is guaranteed to have that property and that method.

The `MapsViewModel` class takes a `MapsRepository` parameter, and `MapsRepository` is just an interface with one function:

```
suspend fun getFeatures(): Resource<FeaturesResponse>
```

You can pass in anything that implements that interface, which `DefaultMapsRepository` does:

```
class DefaultMapsRepository @Inject constructor(
    ...
) : MapsRepository {
```

Since it implements that interface, it needs to implement that `getFeatures` function, which it does:

```
// override is the keyword that shows you're not just declaring a new function,
// it's implementing something abstract in a superclass/interface (or overriding
// an open function)
override suspend fun getFeatures(): Resource<FeaturesResponse> {
    // bla bla
}
```

---

So you can pass in anything at all as your `repository`, so long as it implements `MapsRepository`, meaning you need some implementation of that `getFeatures` function. It doesn't "decide" a version to use, it calls it on whatever you pass in. So you can test it with whatever mock class or object you like

```
val mockRepo = object : MapsRepository {
    override suspend fun getFeatures(): Resource<FeaturesResponse> {
        return Resource.Error("oh snap")
    }
}

val viewModel = MapsViewModel(mockRepo, whateverTheOtherThingIs)
// calls getFeatures() on the repo
viewModel.getFeatures()
```

If none of that makes any sense, you should read up on what interfaces and polymorphism are!

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but as I understand, your example passes in `DefaultMapsRepository` where `getFeatures()` is implemented. But if you would open the project in Android Studio, you would see that if you hover the mouse on `getFeatures()` in `ViewModel`, it would show `MapsRepository` which is the interface and that `repository` dependecy is of type of that interface. Your example in aspect of my project shows that `repository` dependency would be of type `DefaultMapsRepository` in `ViewModel` which would make sense to me because this is where `getFeatures()` is implemented.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense because `repository` is of type `MapsRespository` which is an interface.

Comment: @PCKing `DefaultMapsRepository` **is** a `MapsRepository`. That's one of its types. The object in my example is *not* a ``DefaultMapsRepository``, it doesn't subclass it. It just implements `MapsRepository`, which means it can be used anywhere a `MapsRepository` is required. Anything that's a `MapsRepository` has a function called `getFeatures` with that specific function signature, which is why the VM can call it on whatever's passed in. This is a fundamental part of the language (and Java) and you need to understand it! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Comment: @PCKing if it helps, think of it this way: you could add all kinds of wacky public methods to ``DefaultMapsRepository`` if you like. But if you pass it into that VM constructor as the ``repository`` parameter, the VM *only knows it's a ``MapsRepository``* (i.e. some object that implements that interface). It has no idea that you've actually passed in a ``DefaultMapsRespository`` specifically, it knows nothing about that class or any of those wacky methods. It will just see it as a ``MapsRespository`` with a ``getFeatures`` method, because that's what ``repository`` is defined as

Answer (score 2):

A different way of explaining it that might help. Suppose you have this interface and class.

```
interface Pet {
    fun sayName()
}

class Dog(val name: String): Pet {
    override fun sayName() {
        println(name)
    }
}
```

If some function asks for a Pet, you can pass it an instance of anything that implements the Pet interface.

```
fun sayPetName(pet: Pet) {
    pet.sayName()
}
```

From the function's point of view, it doesn't have to know what class was passed to it. It just knows that whatever was passed to it is an instance of a Pet, and *must* therefore have a *non-abstract* `sayName()` function.

Even though the function `sayName()` is abstract inside the *definition* of the interface, it would be impossible to create an instance of a class where there is an abstract function. There's no such thing as an abstract function in an instance of a class. You can define abstract classes that have abstract functions, but you cannot create instances of them.

You could pass a Dog instance to this function since it qualifies as a Pet. When the function calls `pet.sayName()`, it is up to the instance of Dog to respond. The function itself doesn't have to know anything about what class type was passed to it.

In the same way, if you have an instance of a Pet that was passed to your constructor, your class can use the `sayName()` function on it. If you pass the class a Dog instance, even though the class is storing it in a property that is marked Pet and the class doesn't know it has a Dog, if it calls `sayName()` on it, the Dog instance will use its implementation of `sayName()`.

```
class SomeClass(val pet: Pet) {
    fun sayThePetName() {
        pet.sayName()
    }
}
```

If a Dog were passed to the constructor of the above class, it does not get "downgraded" into a Pet interface that has an abstract function. It's still a Dog instance even if that specific type is not exposed to the class in this scope. The code inside the class doesn't know or care that it's a Dog. It just knows it has a reference to some actual class instance that has the functions defined by the Pet interface.